# Integrating 3rd party libraries in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, highcharts, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I am trying to use a 3rd party library with ZF2; specifically the [Highchartsphp wrapper](https://github.com/ghunti/HighchartsPHP).

I have installed the library using composer but I can not instantiate the `HighchartsPHP` classes from my controller.

When I write `$chart = new Highchart;` I get an error saying the class cannot be found.

Do I need to create an autoloader for this library? If so what are the steps in achieving this?

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Chart2\Model\Chart2;
use Chart2\Form\Chart2Form;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator as paginatorIterator;
use Ghunti\HighchartsPHP\Highchart;

public function high()
{
    $chart = new Highchart();
}
```

Comment: Please add code (including namespaces) where you create the object  and the exact error message otherwise we will all be guessing.

Comment: This is the function I want to be able to call in my controller
    <?php
    `use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;`
    `use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;`
    `use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;`
    `use Chart2\Model\Chart2;          // <-- Add this import`
    `use Chart2\Form\Chart2Form;`       // <-- Add this import
    `use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;`
    `use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator as paginatorIterator;`
     `use Ghunti\HighchartsPHP\Highchart;`
     `public function high()` 
    `{`
    `$chart = new Highchart ();`
        
     `}`
    `}`
    `?>`

Comment: Check if composer autoloader (usually under `vendor/autoload.php`) is even included in your app. E.g., ZF2 skeleton app does that https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/init_autoloader.php#L21